# Python / Matplotlib - How to compute/plot derivative without hard-coding it?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a famous function and its derivative here.
The famous function is the one which arises from the [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).
I wonder if there's some way to calculate the derivative without "hard-coding it"
i.e. by just using some library and calling `derivative(f)` or something like that.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# a,b - the two ends of our interval

a = -2.2
b = +0.25
n = 10

# function f(t) = (1+t)^n - n*t - 1
def f(t):
    '''
    s = 1
    for i in range(n):
        s = s * (1 + 1 * t)
    return s - n * t - 1
    '''
    return np.power(1 + t, n) - n * t - 1

# derivative f'(t) = n*(1+t)^(n-1) - n
def f1(t):
    '''
    s = 1
    for i in range(n-1):
        s = s * (1 + 1 * t)
    return n * s - n
    '''
    return n * np.power(1 + t, n-1) - n

t = np.linspace(a, b, 4000)
g = f(t)
g1 = f1(t)

plt.plot(t, g, 'r') # plotting t, g separately 
plt.plot(t, g1, 'g') # plotting t, g1 separately

plt.axhline(0, color='k')
plt.axvline(0, color='k')

print("=====================")
print(f(-2))
print(f(-1.5))
print(f(-1))
print(f(-0.5))
print(f(0))

print("=====================")
print(f1(-2))
print(f1(-1.5))
print(f1(-1))
print(f1(-0.5))
print(f1(0))

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure_3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org) to calculate the derivative symbolically. If you have a nice mathematical expression, this gives a better accuracy than numerical methods.

Sympy has its own plot functions, but they can be cumbersome if you want to combine many elements. In those cases, it can be easier to use [lambdify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) to convert them to numpy functions.

```py
from sympy import Pow, lambdify
from sympy.abc import t, n

f = Pow(1 + t, n) - n * t - 1
f1 = f.diff(t)  # result: -n + n*(t + 1)**n/(t + 1)

f_np = lambdify(t, f.subs(n, 10))
f1_np = lambdify(t, f1.subs(n, 10))

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

a = -2.2
b = +0.25
x = np.linspace(a, b, 1000)

plt.plot(x, f_np(x), 'r')
plt.plot(x, f1_np(x), 'g')

plt.axhline(0, color='k')
plt.axvline(0, color='k')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Purely staying within sympy, [plotting](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html) can happen as follows:

```py
from sympy import Pow, plot
from sympy.abc import t, n

a = -2.2
b = +0.25
f = Pow(1 + t, n) - n * t - 1
f1 = f.diff(t)
p1 = plot(f.subs(n, 10), (t, a, b), line_color='r', show=False)
p2 = plot(f1.subs(n, 10), (t, a, b), line_color='g', show=False)
p1.append(p2[0])
p1.show()
```

[image: sympy plot]

Comment: Of all approaches here I like your first approach the most. Not sure why. Just seems quite clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Among many others, there are two following methods:

---

**Method 1**

You can use [`derivative`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html) from `scipy` that takes a function `f` and returns its derivative w.r.t `t`. So you don't have to define the derivative function `f1(t)` explicitly.

```
from scipy.misc import derivative

def f(t):
    return np.power(1 + t, n) - n * t - 1

# Rest of the code

t = np.linspace(a, b, 4000)
g = f(t)

plt.plot(t, g, 'r') # plotting t, g separately 
plt.plot(t, derivative(f, t, dx=0.001), 'g')
```

---

**Method 2**

You can use [`gradient`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) function of NumPy which uses central differences and returns the same shape as the input array.

```
t, dt = np.linspace(a, b, 4000, retstep=True)
g1 = np.gradient(f(t), dt)
plt.plot(t, g1, 'g')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Automatic differentiation is a great tool to do this. Check out https://github.com/HIPS/autograd.

```
import autograd.numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from autograd import elementwise_grad as egrad

# a,b - the two ends of our interval

a = -2.2
b = +0.25
n = 10

# function f(t) = (1+t)^n - n*t - 1
def f(t):
    '''
    s = 1
    for i in range(n):
        s = s * (1 + 1 * t)
    return s - n * t - 1
    '''
    return np.power(1 + t, n) - n * t - 1

# derivative f'(t) = n*(1+t)^(n-1) - n
f1 = egrad(f)

t = np.linspace(a, b, 4000)
g = f(t)
g1 = f1(t)

plt.plot(t, g, 'r') # plotting t, g separately 
plt.plot(t, g1, 'g') # plotting t, g1 separately

plt.axhline(0, color='k')
plt.axvline(0, color='k')

print("=====================")
print(f(-2))
print(f(-1.5))
print(f(-1))
print(f(-0.5))
print(f(0))

print("=====================")
print(f1(-2.0))
print(f1(-1.5))
print(f1(-1.0))
print(f1(-0.5))
print(f1(0.0))
```

Note that I had to change the arguments passed to `f1` to be floats, but otherwise it generates the same plot. This is in general how all of the "deep learning" frameworks such as tensorflow, Torch, etc. compute gradients.

This avoids having to analytically compute the derivative yourself and also avoids issues with numerical differentiation.